# Alphanumeric increment in a URL

Tags: python, loops, url, increment, alphanumeric

I am looking to open a window in my browser for every incrementation of an alphanumeric sequence.

Ex: I want to open a different window in the browser for xyz.com/AA1 & xyz.com/AA2&...xyz.com/AB1  ... until xyz.com/ZZ9

I know it will crash my browser but I just want to see the logic of the looping and incrementation that I cant figure out.

I tried os.system to open the web page but it doesnt seem to be possible to increment.

My level of programming is low to very low if every you propose something complexe, I might not have the tools!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `AA1` has three values so you could use three nested `for`-loops. And inside this you can use `os.system()` or `webbrowser.open()` with `"{}{}{}".format(char1, char2, number)`

Comment: insteaf nested `for`-loops you can also use `itertools.product('ABC', 'ABC', '123')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use three nested for-loops

```
for char1 in "ABC":
    for char2 in "ABC":
        for digit in "123":
            print( ''.join((char1, char2, digit)) )
```

or

```
import itertools

for item in itertools.product('ABC', 'ABC', '123'):
    print( ''.join(item) )
```

---

```
import itertools
import string
import webbrowser

CHAR = string.ascii_uppercase
NUMBER = '123456789'

for item in itertools.product(CHAR, CHAR, NUMBER):
    text = ''.join(item)
    url = 'xyz.com/{}'.format(text)
    print(url)
    #webbrowser.open(url)
    #os.system("firefox " + url)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response! 

Works like a charm! 

The only thing is, as expected, it loads all the pages, would there be an easy way to make it load lets say 30 pages at the time? Maybe a timer Time.Sleep() ?

Comment: I don't know for what you want to open urls. If only to see it then `time.sleep()` can be OK. But `time.sleep()` can't control if you closed some window and if it has to open next window to have 30 pages opened. Maybe using `Selenium` which can control window you could control how many tabs you have opened. But in web scraping to scrape 30 pages at the same time you can use threads or porcesses and Pool object which can run 30 workers. When one work ends its job then it uses it with next url. But may not works with `os.system()` and `webbrowser.open()`